# Unused functions in module

Tags: rust

I have a simple base64 encoder/decoder module that I made. It has two functions, one to encode and another to decode.
But if I only want to encode or decode, rustc returns `warning: function never used`.
Do I have to set #[allow(dead_code)] to all my future modules functions, just to stop seeing this warning? I don't want to disable to all dead_code warning.

Edit:
Suggested by @Brian61354270 -> creating a lib crate does solve the problem. I just don't understand why modules work this way

Comment: An alternative would be to put that code in a library crate.

Comment: Does making the functions `pub` make the warning go away?

Comment: @SolomonUcko It doesn't, they have to be pub anyways, since they are in another file.
I guess using "module" rust expect me to use it enterily.

Comment: If they're in a module the complete path of modules to the function has to be `pub` to not warn about unused functions.

Comment: In my base64.rs i have:
`
pub mod base64 {
  pub fn encode() { ... }
}
`
In main.rs I have:
`
mod base64;
fn main() {...}
`
How can I make the complete path `pub`?
@cafce25

Comment: Why do you have a base64 module in your base64 module? Also if you use the function from your main it shouldn't be unused, there seems to be a layer 8 error here. But without a minimum reproducible example, it's difficult to say what exactly, SO doesn't pay for psychic debugging extensions.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I made it harder to understand by simplifying. I have a base64 module because I was learning to use them.
in base64.rs:
`pub mod base64 { pub fn encode() { ... } pub fn decode() { ... } }`
in main.rs:
`mod base64; pub fn main() { base64::base64::encode() }`
Then -> Warning: unused decode(). @Masklinn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost always a bad idea to simply silence warnings like `dead_code` (either by `#[allow(dead_code)]` or just making the functions `pub`) it is there to alert you of possible bugs.
Given this layout of code:

```rust
fn main() {}

pub fn doit_a() {}
fn doit_b() {}

mod priv {
    pub fn doit_c() {}
    fn doit_d() {}
}

pub mod pu {
    pub fn doit_e() {}
    fn doit_f() {}
}
```

- `doit_a` does not generate a warning it's exported
- `doit_b` generates a warning because it's not used here and not exported it's therefore impossible to use and can just be removed
- `doit_c` and `doit_d` neither is reachable from another crate, and neither is used  it's therefore impossible to use and can just be removed
- `doit_e` since both the module it's defined in and the function itself are public it's reachable from other crates and does not generate a warning
- `doit_f` the module it's defined in is public but the function itself isn't unless we use it internally we could just remove it
- `main` is a special case:

  - in binary crates not a warning since `main` is the entry point used
  - in library crates same as `doit_b`

All warnings are generated because

- the compiler assumes every module is included exactly once
- the local code doesn't use it
- external code can't use it

therefore it's very likely that the developer has made a mistake somewhere (a typo, failed to adjust some code to use new functions, ...), or is not ready with writing the module yet.

It seems you're using modules as a way to have a reusable piece of code, but they are not designed to be by themselves, that's where library crates come in. Instead they're only meant to be used in a single crate and group similar functionality.